# Algorithm to convert set of linked lines to 2D shape?

Tags: vector, geometry

I would like to convert a set of lines linked at various nodes to a 2D 'face' shape. This is most easily demonstrated with a diagram:
[image: lines to 2D face]

I want to go from the lines on the left to the shape on the right. My question is, is there an existing algorithm to do this? Ideally one implemented in python, but other options would be welcome.

Comment: It is not really a duplicate, because the topology in the other question is different - just line segments connected end to end. This question involves branching. If the other question had a robust answer (which it doesn't) it would not be guaranteed to work on the topology in this question.

Comment: I've decided I agree and nominated for reopening. If you still agree you could add a vote. I've actually found at least one answer to the question now, so I might like to turn it into a community wiki.

Comment: I'm sorry I can't vote to reopen because I don't yet have 3000 rep. I look forward to seeing your solution though.

Comment: Well, a link to someone else's solution: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/226569/Drawing-polylines-by-tessellation